# Как запустить прокси с авторизацией Selenide

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

Я что-то нашел

```
Selenide.open("https://whoer.net/ru",
                "21.39.59.2:6767",
                "login",
                "password");
```

но оно не работает. Мне желательно не окстылями делать, по типу отправка таба, заполнение формы и тп, а чтобы функцией все было, есть ли такая функция в Selenide?

Ошибка:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}) on port 10255
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
мар 14, 2020 10:31:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Далее после ошибки все дальше запускается, но прокси не работает

Пробовал с Configurations, но все равно просит пароль, хотя в open, я оставил все так же с адресом прокси, логином и паролем

```
    Configuration.browser = "chrome";
            Configuration.proxyEnabled=true;
            Configuration.proxyHost="21.39.59.2";
            Configuration.proxyPort=6767;
```

slf4j

```
94 [main] INFO com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer  - No webdriver is bound to current thread: 1 - let's create a new webdriver
2157 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory  - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
2169 [main] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl  - netty-tcnative not in the classpath; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable.
2825 [main] DEBUG com.browserup.bup.mitm.manager.ImpersonatingMitmManager  - Allowed ciphers for proxy connections to upstream servers (some ciphers may not be available): [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2825 [main] DEBUG com.browserup.bup.mitm.manager.ImpersonatingMitmManager  - Allowed ciphers for client connections to proxy (some ciphers may not be available): [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2919 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap  - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
2919 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap  - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
2935 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent  - Platform: Windows
2950 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0  - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
2950 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0  - Java version: 8
2950 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0  - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
2950 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0  - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
2950 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0  - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
2950 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0  - direct buffer constructor: available
2966 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0  - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
2966 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0  - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable prior to Java9
2966 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0  - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): available
2966 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent  - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
2966 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent  - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\E6D8~1\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
2966 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent  - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
2966 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent  - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: 1308622848 bytes
2966 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent  - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
2966 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava6  - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
2966 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent  - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
2966 [main] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer  - Starting proxy at address: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:0
2982 [main] DEBUG org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ServerGroup  - Initializing thread pools for TCP with 2 acceptor threads, 8 incoming worker threads, and 8 outgoing worker threads
2982 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup  - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 4
2997 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop  - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
2997 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop  - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
3028 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent  - org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
3060 [main] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer  - Proxy listening with TCP transport
3091 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId  - -Dio.netty.processId: 9200 (auto-detected)
3091 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil  - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
3091 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil  - -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
3310 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil  - Loopback interface: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1, 127.0.0.1)
3321 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil  - Failed to get SOMAXCONN from sysctl and file \proc\sys\net\core\somaxconn. Default: 200
3556 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId  - -Dio.netty.machineId: 44:6d:57:ff:fe:da:46:dc (auto-detected)
3588 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector  - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
3588 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector  - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
3634 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 4
3650 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 4
3650 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
3650 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
3650 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
3650 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512
3650 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
3650 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
3650 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
3650 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
3650 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimIntervalMillis: 0
3650 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: true
3650 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator  - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedByteBuffersPerChunk: 1023
3666 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil  - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
3666 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil  - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
3666 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil  - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
3713 [main] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer  - Proxy started at address: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:60514
3728 [main] DEBUG com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory  - browser=chrome
3744 [main] DEBUG com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory  - browser.version=null
3744 [main] DEBUG com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory  - remote=null
3744 [main] DEBUG com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory  - browserSize=1366x768
3744 [main] DEBUG com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory  - startMaximized=false
3775 [main] DEBUG com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.ChromeDriverFactory  - Chrome options: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: chrome, pageLoadStrategy: normal, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=ПК...}
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}) on port 26020
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
мар 16, 2020 1:57:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
6163 [main] INFO com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.BrowserResizer  - Set browser size to 1366x768
6327 [main] INFO com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory  - BrowserName=chrome Version=80.0.3987.132 Platform=WINDOWS
6327 [main] INFO com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory  - Selenide v. 5.9.0
6327 [main] INFO com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory  - Selenium WebDriver v. 3.141.59 build time: 2018-11-14T08:25:48
6327 [main] INFO com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.CreateDriverCommand  - Create webdriver in current thread 1: ChromeDriver -> ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (3e3aa4932935c30fb24a2173695db6ab)
```

Comment: Вижу в логе такую строчку:
DefaultHttpProxyServer  - Proxy started at address: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:60514

Это значит, что эти настройки не используются:
Configuration.proxyHost="21.39.59.2";
Configuration.proxyPort=6767;

Значит, вы их как-то не так или не вовремя задаёте.

Comment: `Configuration.proxyEnabled=true;
   Configuration.proxyHost="21.39.59.2";
   Configuration.proxyPort=6767;
   Selenide.open("http://myip.ru/",
                 "21.39.59.2:6767","login","password");`- Сделал все так, все равно запрашивает пароль